# Error while building ITK: libITKCommon-4.2.dll is not existing after build with MinGW

Tags: mingw, itk

I am having this error while building ITK library using MinGW generator.
After built while building a program I got error :

mingw32-make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'C:/ITK/mingwbin/lib/libITKCommon-4.2.dll.a', needed by 'Events.exe'.

I checked in ITK build folder there were no libITKCommon-4.2.dll.a file.
Is this error related to build error?
Please help me to solve this.

I have attached screenshots of errors.

Thanks
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIzXM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The error referenced relates to a bug in MingGW's GCC inclusion of the
float.h header.

A workaround has been merge into ITK:

http://itk.org/gitweb?p=ITK.git;a=commit;h=399018e1de41e9499e79d498380458b95671d796

Please use ITK Git master or ITK 4.5 when it is released.